# Django rest / react. Deleting cookie not working on local host

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-cookies

I have a django res application that sets a http only cookie on login. I also have a log out view that will remove this cookie.

```
class LogoutAPI(APIView):
def post(self, request):
    response = Response(request)
    if request.COOKIES.get("refresh_token") is not None:
        response.delete_cookie("refresh_token")
        response.data = {
            "details": "successfully logged out"
        } 
    else:
        response.data = {
            "details": "user already logged out"
        }
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_208_ALREADY_REPORTED
    return response
```

My django app is running on 127.0.0.1:8000.

The cookie is deleted as expected if I use 127.0.0.1:3000 to view my react app, but does not delete if use localhost:3000

Why is this?

for reference, this is how my cookie is set (both 127 and localhost receive this in the browser cookies correctly)

```
response.set_cookie("refresh_token", str(refresh), httponly=True, expires=expire, samesite="None", secure=True)
```